# Paired t.test gives no result for NA

Tags: r, statistics, na

I am comparing measurements from 3 experiments using paired t test.
However, I am getting no results if some values are missing (are `NA`)

data:

```
dat <- read.table(text='sample  G1  G2  G3
S1   0.002458717   0.01045769    0.003770503
S2   0.010009784   0.02465088    0.011505804
S3   NA            NA            0.006403423
S1   0.003458717   0.01145769    0.004770503
S2   0.011009784   0.02565088    0.012505804
S3   NA            NA            0.007403423
S1   0.001458717   0.00945769    0.002770503
S2   0.009009784   0.02365088    0.010505804
S3   NA            NA            0.0054034232', header=TRUE)
```

Note that G1/2/3 are not independent measurements, but represent different genes that have been tested. They are not related and each G requires a t.test for it's own.

t.test:

```
sig<-lapply(dat[-1], function(x) 
  pairwise.t.test(x, dat$sample,
                  p.adjust.method = "BH"))



 > sig
    $G1

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

    data:  x and dat$sample 

       S1 S2
    S2 -  - 
    S3 -  - 

    P value adjustment method: BH 

    $G2

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

    data:  x and dat$sample 

       S1 S2
    S2 -  - 
    S3 -  - 

    P value adjustment method: BH 

    $G3

        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

    data:  x and dat$sample 

       S1      S2     
    S2 0.00024 -      
    S3 0.01803 0.00117

P value adjustment method: BH
```

I understand why there is no comparison between S1/2 and S3 for G1/2, as the values are missing. However, I don't get why there is no result for comparing S1 and S2?

Thank you!

Comment: can you remove NA's? `lapply(2:4, function(x)  { 
  tmp <- na.omit(dat[,c(1,x)])
  pairwise.t.test(tmp[,2], tmp$sample)
  })`

Comment: you need at least 2 observations per group to obtain p values. In you example S3 is completly missing for G1 and G2. Thus, remove factor levels with observations < 2.

Comment: Thanks @Jimbou. I know that I need at least 2 abservations and that therefor, I will not get p values for comparisons between groups where one group has NAs, this is no issue. However, I don't get any p values, even when comparing groups that have 3 observations (S1 vs S2). I'll try to implement your solution that removes NAs

Answer (score 0):

For `pairwise.t.test` you need a response and a grouping vector; so the problem is with the data format, and not with the `NA`s. You'll just need to convert data from `dat` accordingly (see `?pairwise.t.test` for more details).

Here is one way using the base R function `stack`:

```
# Convert wide to long dataframe, then select values 
val <- stack(dat, select = -sample)$values;

# Sample labels (the grouping vector)
grp <- rep(dat$sample, 3);


pairwise.t.test(val, grp, p.adjust.method = "BH");
#    
#        Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD
#    
#data:  val and grp
#
#   S1     S2
#S2 0.0031 -
#S3 0.8160 0.0319
```

Note that `NA`s will automatically be omitted (by default).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I think my example wasn't clear, G1/2/3 are actually non related. They are not the 3 measurements I would like to compare. That is why used lapply, to perform a paired t test for every column each. The data actually is in a long format